# Cursor positioned on the right side instead on the left

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why the cursor is positioned on the right side, instead on the left.

```js
$('.legoact').focus();
```

```css
.lego{
  background:#ddd;
  width:70%;
  margin:14px;
  position:relative;
}

.mark{
  position:absolute;
  right:-9px; top:-9px;
  width:14px; height:14px;
  border:2px solid white;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class='lego legotxt legoact' contenteditable='true'>
  <div class='mark' id='mark' contenteditable='false'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you said `right: -9px`

Comment: @sadrzadehsina, `-9px` is for `mark` not for `lego`

Comment: Adding to @sadrzadehsina comment, the `.mark` element is only 14px wide, if you make it wider you'll see that the prompt is actually positioned to the left of the of it.

Comment: @Danny and why? Why `mark` has focus and not `lego`?

Comment: just remove `right: -9px` and put `left: -9px` if you want it on the left but offset in the same way

Comment: @RobinZigmond, `mark` should be on the right, not on the left. What does it mean - `offset in the same way`

Comment: @puerto then I'm confused by your question "Why the cursor is positioned on the right side, instead on the left.". I thought you wanted it on the left, not the right. If you're happy with it on the right, what is your question?

Comment: @RobinZigmond, `mark` is a div - it should be right. `cursor` is a `caret` - it should be left

Comment: Oh, you mean the actual cursor where you input your text. Sorry, yes I did misunderstand. You can't directly manipulate this with CSS/JS as far as I know, but it looks like @blex below found a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.focus()`, the caret will be placed at the beginning of the content. Here, the first content is your `#mark` div, so the cursor is placed right before it. You can see that when pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, it will be removed:

```js
$('.legoact').focus();
```

```css
.lego{
background:#ddd;
width:70%;
margin:14px;
position:relative;
}

.mark{
 position:absolute;
 right:-9px; top:-9px;
 width:14px; height:14px;
 border:2px solid white;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:red;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='lego legotxt legoact' contenteditable='true'>
<div class='mark' id='mark' contenteditable='false'></div>
</div>
```

I *think* you don't want this to happen. The mark is not part of the content you want to edit. To solve this problem, you can use a wrapping div:

```js
$('.input').focus();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.mark {
  position: absolute;
  right: -9px; top: -9px;
  width: 14px; height: 14px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='input' contenteditable='true'></div>
  <div class='mark'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why the cursor is positioned on the right side, instead on the left ?**

`contenteditable` is meant for plain texts. The parent has `contenteditable` but the child is an HTML element.
Now the position of the cursor depends of the element try structure of your `markup/HTML`.

Example: If you had 2 children inside `contenteditable` as follows, the cursor would be displayed near `mark2`.

```
<div class='lego legotxt legoact' contenteditable='true'>
    <div class='mark2'></div> <!-- Cursor will be displayed at the starting of this div -->
    <div class='mark1'></div>
</div>
```

**How to fix this ?**

Check this : https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/5f5a87

It has the complete solution.

Comment: so usefull, thnaks